# Iterating through array in a block for sorting it´s members

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

How do I get the object at `[index]` inside a block like this? it´s for the purpose of getting it´s first letter and sorting the array of NSDictionaries lexicographically.

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [_photos sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = _photos[0][FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];
    NSString *second = _photos[0][FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
_photos = sortedArray;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have an array of dictionaries. To sort on the value of the `FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE` key, you do:

```
_photos = [_photos sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
    NSString *first = a[FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];
    NSString *second = b[FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```